# Selenium Element Display Property

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have html elements structured as below:

```
<div style="display:none">
<div id="myElementId">SOME MESSAGE</div>
</div>
```

I want to find out when the "myElementId" is displayed. On a click of button I

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium Webdriver you can use [WebElement.isDisplayed()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed%28%29) to check if an element is visible.